# Any sulution for an onload return?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, return, onload

I'm a newbie in javascript and write a little app, but I know that `onload` an asynchronously function is and return not work.
Have anyone an idea?

[See this](https://jsfiddle.net/21L6hrkm/)

Thanks for your help

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (function1()){
        if (getDBsettings()){
            if (function3()){
                dostuff;
            }
            else{
                alert("");
            }
        }
        else{
           alert(""); 
        }                     
    }
    else{                    
       alert(""); 
    }
}

    function getDBsettings(){
    var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://abcdefgh.php", false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onload = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            var json_string = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var json = JSON.parse(json_string);
            if(json.success===1){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(xmlhttp.status == 404){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) on MDN  has a yellow note saying "You need to add the event listeners before calling open() on the request.  Otherwise the progress events will not fire." Related?

Comment: Also the onload function is a callback for an asynchronous request  and does not affect the value returned by function `getDBsettings` which, in fact, returns `undefined`.